# Acting on a variable changing in python

Tags: python, variables

So I'm trying to make a Hospital sim (text based) and there is an option to recruit more staff. I've figured out how to limit the amount of times they can recruit (limit of 350 staff) and the amount they get is supposed to be random (random.choice(staffrec), but once the random number is generated from staffrec it stays the same and I want the code to be run again with a different outcome. Here is my code. (Sorry for the length, I've put all of it so I don't miss anything)

```
import time
import random

staff = 100
wards = 20
beds = 140
patients = 80

staffrec = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
staffrec = random.choice(staffrec)


option = ""

print("Welcome to Hospital Simulator!")

print("You have to manage the hospital with patients coming in,")
print("Staff recruitement and staff quitting,")
print("and how many beds and wards are available!")

Aopt = ["A", "a"]
Bopt = ["B", "b"]
Copt = ["C", "c"]
Dopt = ["D", "d"]
Eopt = ["E", "e"]
Fopt = ["F", "f"]

while staff <= 350:
    staffrec = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    staffrec = random.choice(staffrec)
    staff = staff + staffrec

while option != Fopt:
    option = input("""What would you like to do:
A: View number of patients
B: View number of beds
C: View number of wards
D: View number of staff
E: Recruit more staff
F: Quit\n""")

    if option in Aopt:
        print("You currently have " + str(patients) + " patients\n")

    if option in Bopt:
        print("You currently have " + str(beds) + " beds\n")

    if option in Copt:
        print("You have " + str(wards) + " wards\n")

    if option in Dopt:
        print("You currently have " + str(staff) + " staff\n")

    if option in Eopt:
        print("You try and recruit more staff. You recruit " + str(staffrec) + " staff\n")
        if staff > 350:
            print("You cannot recruit any more staff!")

    if option in Fopt:
        print("Goodbye!")
        break
```

There have been other posts related to this subject using classes, but since I'm fairly new to python I didn't totally understand them. :3 Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Peter

Answer (score 0):

You assign the value of `staffrec` before the main game logic and never update with a new random value, so its value will be the same each time you enter the loop block which adds the new recruits. If you want it to change each time just call the `random` only when you need the random number.

I would also sugest using the [`randint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) method over choice, since it will generate a random number between any two values. For example, `random.randint(0, 100)` wil return a random number between 0 and 100.

See below:

```py
if option in Eopt:
    staffrec = random.randint(1, 9)
    staff = staffrec

    print("You try and recruit more staff. You recruit " + str(staffrec) + " staff\n")
    if staff > 350:
        print("You cannot recruit any more staff!")
```

Comment: actually, op assigns the value of ```staffrec``` more than once, and 350 times in the while loop

Comment: It still happens before anything else is done and remains the same at each iteration of the option selection loop so it never changes the value of `staffrec`

Answer (score 0):

to my understanding you want to keep track of the previous choice and if the new choice is the same as previous choice it should try choosing again until it gets a new value, here's my take on this:

```
prev_staffrec = None
staffrec = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

def choose_staffrec():
    global prev_staffrec # to make sure you're accessing it in the global scope
    staffrec2 = random.choice(staffrec)
    if staffrec2 == prev_staffrec:
        choose_staffrec() # run the function again if it's the same
    return staffRec2
```

this eliminates the need to create staffrec over and over again
now anywhere you have the lines

```
staffrec = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
staffrec = random.choice(staffrec)
```

you can replace with:

```
choose_staffrec()
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the forum,

A few things stand out to me about your code:

```
staffrec = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
staffrec = random.choice(staffrec)
```

These two lines contribute nothing, since you're replacing the value of `staffrec` later on anyways. Additionally, as a rule of thumb, avoid reusing variable names, especially if you're reassigning them with completely different types (`staffrec` was a list, now it's an integer).

This loop:

```
while staff <= 350:
    staffrec = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    staffrec = random.choice(staffrec)
    staff = staff + staffrec
```

Seems redundant, and it doesn't actually limit `staff` to a maximum of 350. Using this approach, when the loop ends, `staff` will always be between 351 and 359.
What do you want the actual range to be? Why do you need a loop for this? Just use `random.randint` to generate a number within a fixed range.

This condition:

```
while option != Fopt:
```

Will never be false. `option` will always be a string, and a string will never be equal to a tuple. Since you use `break` later on to break out of the loop anyway, you might as well turn this into `while True:`.

If I understood the question correctly, you want to know how to generate a new value for `staff` (by rerunning the while-loop from before). You could wrap it in a function, but that seems unnecessary - simply use `random.randint` to generate a new value, like I mentioned earlier.